# Jacobi field on polygonal mesh

Tags: geodesic, discrete-geometry

I want to compute Jacobi fields on polygonal meshes. The problem is that on each face, two geodesics starting parallel will remain parallel until they pass a vertex from different sides. Passing a vertex, where the Gaussian curvature is a delta function, the geodesics immediately intersect (By the Jacobi equation).

What is the generalization of the Jacobi fields in discrete differential geometry?

Thank you in advance.